# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Delete from database error

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, crud

I'm having this issue where I try to delete an entry from my database and, while doing so in my html page, getting an error page instead of where I want to be redirrected.
The entry I'm trying to delete is 'order'.
This is my Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "supplier/orders/review")
    public String reviewOrders(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("orders", ordersRepository.findAll());
        return "ReviewOrders";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteOrder/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteOrder(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
        Orders orders = ordersRepository.getById(id);
        ordersRepository.delete(orders);
        return "redirect:/SupplierDashboard";
    }
```

this is my html

```
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="orders:${orders}" class="table-row">
            <td th:text="${orders.id}">Id</td>
            <td th:text="${orders.product_name}">Name</td>
            <td th:text="${orders.product.price}">Price</td>
            <td th:text="${orders.product.description}">desc</td>
            <td th:text="${orders.product.category}">category</td>
            <td th:text="${orders.product.quantity}">quantity</td>
            <td th:text="${orders.product.supplier.firstName}">supplier name</td>
            <td>
                <a th:href="@{/deleteOrder/{id} (id = ${orders.id})}" class="btn btn-danger ml-2">Delete</a>
            </td>
```

the url I'm redirrected to is  `http://localhost:8080/deleteOrder/1` and I get this error:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jun 21 22:49:08 EEST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I've tried just about everything I've seen on other questions. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Does the `"supplier/orders/review` work as expected? from the limited logging it might be that the controller class is not initiated which could be because the component scanning does not pick it up.

Comment: If you're doing a `"redirect:"`, it needs to return a url.  It looks like you're trying to return a template since `/SupplierDashboard` looks more like `ReviewOrders` than `supplier/orders/review`.

Answer (score 1):

Break it down one step at a time.

Do a print statement to see if the id gets printed before you get an error.
Check if you're getting the right order again a print statement goes a long way.

Also when you redirect it needs a get method. I say this because I assume you have a mapping for SupplierDashboard and html/thymeleaf template created in your controller so check if its a post or a get.

Your id might not be printing in your java code which could be causing the issue.